# No Sound or Brightness indicator

Tags: indicator, indicator-sound

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I usually use unity but I've been working on setting up an i3 config. All of a sudden there are no volume or brightness indicators when I change the volume/brightness with my media keys. I haven't been able to find anything regarding this and would like to get it fixed, if possible.